# to_tsquery как использовать спецсимволы и целые слова

Tags: postgresql

У меня есть поле в базе в формате ts_vector
Я хочу делать по нему поиск и у меня возникло несколько проблем. 
Первая: например я хочу найти слова digital и marketing, есть вариант когда они идут подряд, и тут все ок, и может быть вариант когда они идут не подряд - тогда мне не подходит поиск по корню слова, как мне сделать поиск по точному соответствию?
Вторая: например я ищу названия брендов, как H&M или M&M - в этом случае & воспринимается как оператор, мне же нужно точное совпадение.

Comment: `'digital:*&marketing:*'` не годится?

Comment: Как раз этот вариант возвращает в несколько раз больше результатов, в большей части которых нет одного из слов